# jQuery changing toggle button symbols

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I have situation like this: I have an menu and it's only shows up, then the button is clicked. Everything works fine, except when after menu is open, I want it to close. The button symbol is not changing and stuck on "close". What I did wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".menu-button").click(function () {
         $(".first-page nav").slideToggle(500);
     });
     if ($('.menu-button').hasClass("menu-open")) {
         $('.menu-button').on('click', function () {
             $(this).removeClass('menu-open');
             $(this).addClass('menu-close');
         });
     }
     if ($('.menu-button').hasClass("menu-close")) {
         $('.menu-button').on('click', function () {
             $(this).removeClass('menu-close');
             $(this).addClass('menu-open');
         });
     }
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a0kscpa3/

Comment: You don't need separate click events. Define the click event and add the if conditions into it.

Comment: `$('.menu-button').on('click', function(){` is not even getting called. put a alert and you would see that it's not called.

Comment: couldn't edit my above comment.. hence mentioning here.. I meant to say the "second" `$('.menu-button').on('click', function(){` will never be called..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always tidy the JS up by simplifying the function so that there are no conditional statements or multiple click events.

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22wcb4z1/)

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu').stop().slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-open');
});
```

Also the [jQuery stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function is used to prevent the animation from being queued when the user clicks multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment, Your second `if` condition in original post will never be called. And as @Tyr said, you need to apply condition like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu-button").click(function () {
        $(".first-page nav").slideToggle(500);
    });

    $('.menu-button').on('click', function () {

        if ($('.menu-button').hasClass("menu-open")) {

            $(this).removeClass('menu-open');
            $(this).addClass('menu-close');
        }
       else if ($('.menu-button').hasClass("menu-close")) {
            $(this).removeClass('menu-close');
            $(this).addClass('menu-open');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var flag= false;
        $(".menu-button").click(function(){
            $(".first-page nav").slideToggle(500);
            if(flag==false){
                flag = true;
                $(this).removeClass('menu-open');
                $(this).addClass('menu-close');
            }else{
                flag = false;
                $(this).removeClass('menu-close'); 
                $(this).addClass('menu-open');
            }
        });


    });
```